# php get the matching values from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I Have two arrays like this

```
$array1 = Array ( [0] => Dutch [1] => Kannada [2] => Vietnamese [3] => Belarusian );
$array2 = Array ( [0] => English [1] => Germany [2] => Vietnamese [3] => Spanish [4] => Hindi );
```

I want to get the same values present in both arrays. So for that I used `array_intersect` like this

```
<?php
$array1 = Array ( [0] => Dutch [1] => Kannada [2] => Vietnamese [3] => Belarusian );
$array2 = Array ( [0] => English [1] => Germany [2] => Vietnamese [3] => Spanish )
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

But its not showing the matching values. Even it is showing the error like

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

I think the array code structure is fine then why I am getting this error and not getting the matching values from two arrays? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: The output of `print_r()` is not valid PHP array syntax.

Comment: [Newuser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614208/newuser)  This error is becaouse of your array element are not comma(,) seprated. So after each element its expecting array to be closed.  It sould be , seprated like this        $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(First you declared your array wrong and forgot a `;`)

```
$array1 = array ("Dutch", "Kannada", "Vietnamese", "Belarusian");
$array2 = array ("English", "Germany", "Vietnamese", "Spanish");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [2] => Vietnamese )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 

$array1 = Array ( '0' => 'Dutch', '1' => 'Kannada', '2' => 'Vietnamese', '3' => 'Belarusian' );
$array2 = Array ( '0' => 'English', '1' => 'Germany','2' => 'Vietnamese', '3' => 'Spanish' );
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

output:`Array ( [2] => Vietnamese )`

Comment: You should have quotes around the strings `Dutch`, `Kannada`, etc.